# Fetch value from SharePoint JSON output

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am getting below JSON object from a Sharepoint list. How can I get the value for Company in the Data operation ( select) for logic apps. I did item()['Company']?['Value'] and it is not working. Any suggestions?

```
"body": [
  {
    "Company": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
      "Id": 0,
      "Value": "Test1"
    },
    "Date From": "2022-03-30",
    "Date To": "2022-03-31",
    "Title": "Title 1"
  },
  {
    "Company": {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
      "Id": 2,
      "Value": "Line2"
    },
    "Date From": "2022-03-21",
    "Date To": "2022-03-29",
    "Title": "Title 2"
  }
]
}
```

I am fetching share-point list and then using data operations (select) to get the JSON as output.

I need JSON in the below format so that I can pass this to stored procedure and insert into the Azure SQL DB. I have another 12 items in the list.

```
         [
          {
            "Company": "Test1",
            "Date From": "2022-03-30",
            "Date To": "2022-03-31",
            "Title": "Title 1"
          },
          {
            "Company": "Line2",
            "Date From": "2022-03-21",
            "Date To": "2022-03-29",
            "Title": "Title 2"
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than select, you can set a variable.  We're all different but that makes far more sense to me.

[image: Flow]

Your expression is much the same, I used ...

```
item()['Company']['Value']
```

Just make sure you initialise the variable outside and prior to the `For each` ...

[image: Variable]

This is the result for the first item in the array ...

[image: Result]

To compile a full JSON object and add it to an array, again, simply use a variable and specify the values as need be.

Firstly, initialize your array outside of the `For each` ...

[image: Array Variable]

... and then in the `For each`, add an object to the array variable on each loop (make sure you include the quotes around the expression where required) ...

[image: Add Object to Array]

You just have to compile the JSON.  The end result will look like this ...

[image: Result]

This is the JSON in full ...

```
[
  {
    "Company": "Line2",
    "Date From": "2022-03-21",
    "Date To": "2022-03-29",
    "Title": "Title 2"
  },
  {
    "Company": "Test1",
    "Date From": "2022-03-30",
    "Date To": "2022-03-31",
    "Title": "Title 1"
  }
]
```

Also, you'll notice my list has come out in a different order, that's because the `For each` runs in parallel, if you need to avoid that, change the settings so it runs in a single thread ...

[image: Concurrency]

This is the JSON definition of the LogicApp, you can load it into your tenant and test with it ...

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_SQL_Array": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "SQL Array",
                            "value": {
                                "Company": "@{item()['Company']['Value']}",
                                "Date From": "@{item()['Date From']}",
                                "Date To": "@{item()['Date To']}",
                                "Title": "@{item()['Title']}"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('SharePoint JSON')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_SQL_Array": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_SQL_Array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "SQL Array",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_SharePoint_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_SharePoint_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "SharePoint JSON",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "Company": {
                                        "Id": 0,
                                        "Value": "Test1",
                                        "odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"
                                    },
                                    "Date From": "2022-03-30",
                                    "Date To": "2022-03-31",
                                    "Title": "Title 1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Company": {
                                        "Id": 2,
                                        "Value": "Line2",
                                        "odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"
                                    },
                                    "Date From": "2022-03-21",
                                    "Date To": "2022-03-29",
                                    "Title": "Title 2"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Result",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@variables('SQL Array')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: I got your point. I want to make one consolidated JSON and want to insert into the SQL table. How can I consolidated other items. I have other list items like this (close to 10+) making variable for each I feel might not good options. what do you suggest.

Comment: Reword your question with what you want and I'll answer it.  What format does the SQL call need?  JSON or something else?  Whatever is needed, please provide an example.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: how are you getting Company.value in the append to sql. In my case it is asking me to select the sharepoint list item and there is nothing with .value in it.

Comment: I've given you that answer, it's the expression I mentioned in my answer.  Let me add the code view for that variable setting to the answer.

Comment: I don't have a SharePoint list output, I have a variable with your JSON so it's slightly different, I can't help beyond that because I don't have access to your tenant so can't reproduce completely.